# jquery simple dropdown multiple trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to build a simple jQuery dropdown with 2 dropdown menus. Here is the jQuery code I'm using:

```
 $('.myDropdown .classes .logo').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.myDropdown .classes .dropdown.class-dropdown').slideUp(300, function(){
        $('.myDropdown .classes .dropdown.school-dropdown').slideDown();
    });
});

$('.myDropdown .classes .name').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.myDropdown .classes .dropdown.school-dropdown').slideUp(300, function(){
        $('.myDropdown .classes .dropdown.class-dropdown').slideDown();
    });
});

$('.myDropdown .classes ').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.myDropdown .classes .dropdown').slideUp();
});
```

My issue is: I'm getting multiple fires of the slidedown and slideup actions for how ever many times the mouse moves in and out the logo or name elements, thus giving a bounce type effect until the number of mouse ins and outs has finished.

I tried using stop but O couldn't get it to work right.

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle? I want to do a deeper look at your code.

Comment: You have the class myDropdown and classes in both of your jQuery selectors (and the fucntions) why not eliminate redundancy and just target .logo or .name?

Comment: thats not very constructive i know that. i have a lot more code that i can't post, i put the min

Comment: Can you post your html?  There is no way to give a straight-forward answer without your markup